# Bootstrap [3.3.4] -- <table class="table table-striped"> How to properly pull-right a <td> cell

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Version 3.3.4 seems to have improved how pull-right works inside a striped table.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column A</th>
                <th>Column B</th>
                <th>Column C</th>
                <th>Column D</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Stuff</td>
            <td>More Stuff</td>
            <td class="pull-right">Right aligned! 100</td>
            <td>Last Stuff</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

If you view this then you'll see subtle change in the table's striped pattern on Column C

Question 1: Is there a better way to do column data with right aligned data?

Question 2: is it possible to do that without custom CSS?

Question 3: Is it possible to use a simmer technique on the column headers? They too appear to lose formatting when pulled right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has **.text-right** css class. In my projects, I am using this class to align the cell data in right side.

https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/110/

```
<td class="text-right">Right aligned! 100</td>
```

if you want to center align the header or any cell data, use **.text-center**

see this fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/111/

Comment: Addresses the header challenges as well.